# What happens to the Eigenvalues of $\nabla^2$ as the radius of the circle increases?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, partial-differential-equations

**Question**

Formulate a variational characterization of the eigenvalues of $\nabla^2$ whose eigenfunctions satisfy $$\begin{cases} -\nabla^2 \phi=\lambda\phi \ \ &x\in B(0,a)\\ \phi=0 \ \ &x\in \partial B(0,a)\end{cases},$$ where $B(x,r)$ is the two dimensional circle centered at $x$ of radius $r$. **What happens to the eigenvalues $\lambda$ as the $a$ increases?**

**Attempt**

In order the formulate the variational characterization, I multiplied both sides of  $-\nabla^2 u=\lambda u$ by $u$ and integrated over the given region. This eventually led me to $$\lambda=\frac{\int_{B(0,a)} \lvert \nabla u \rvert ^2 \ dx}{\int_{B(0,a)} u^2 \ dx}.$$ So the variation characterization is $$I(u)=\frac{\int_{B(0,a)} \lvert \nabla u \rvert ^2 \ dx}{\int_{B(0,a)} u^2 \ dx},$$ and the minimizer of this functional will be the eigenfunction of the operator. How can I use this to say something about the eigenvalues as $a$ increases? I attempted to convert $I(u)$ into polar coordinates and got 
$$I(u(r,\theta))=\frac{\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^ar(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r})^2+\frac{1}{r}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta})^2 \ dr d\theta}{\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^au^2(r,\theta)r \ dr \ d\theta}.$$ Next, I was hoping to find an appropriate test function (one that satisfied the initial value problem ) and use it to bound the eigenvalues through the min-max principle. So far, though, every test function I've tried causes the numerator to diverge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u(x)$ be the solution on the unit ball. The corresponding eigenvalue is $\lambda$. Define $v(x) = u(x/a)$ on ball $B(0, a)$.

$$\nabla v(x) = \frac{1}{a}\nabla u$$
$$-\nabla^2v = -\frac{1}{a^2}\nabla^2 u = \frac{1}{a^2}\lambda u =\frac{1}{a^2}\lambda v $$

So the corresponding eigenvalue for the ball $B(0, \alpha)$ is $\lambda_{\alpha} = \frac{\lambda}{\alpha^2}$